# Error de dependencias al tratar de crear app react

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, npm, leaflet

mi proyecto de react cuando trato de hacer build, funciona bien cuando ejectuto el comando "npm start" para crear y montarlo en el servidor local, pero al tratar de construirlo con "npm build" obtengo este error:

Failed to compile.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'leaflet' in '/Users/robertramirez/Documents/Coding projects/React projects/react-portfolio/node_modules/react-leaflet/esm'
```

Igualmente cuanto trato de hacer deploy ya sea en github-pages o netlify tengo el mismo error pero además me da un poco más de detalles:

```
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!
7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! While resolving: react-leaflet@3.2.5
    3:49 AM: Creating deploy upload records
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.x" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.18
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"^0.1.18" from the root project
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   6 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-loaders, ...)
    7:23:49 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-leaflet@3.2.5
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react-leaflet
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   react-leaflet@"^3.2.5" from the root project
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.1" from react-leaflet@3.2.5
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-leaflet
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!     react-leaflet@"^3.2.5" from the root project
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR!
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    7:23:49 AM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: El problema es que usas la versión 18.0.0 de react, y la versión de react-leaflet que usas requiere react 17. Según un comentario en su github, puedes probar con el `--force`del npm install: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/978 eso, o utilizar la nueva versión (4.0) que ya requiere react 18: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/releases

Comment: Gracias! ese era el problema, el flag --force force no funcionó, tuve que desinstalar la versión antigua react-leaflet y posteriormente instalar la más actual y ya funciona.